Hiddur mitzvah for Lechem Mishneh
Is there any chiyuv in Halacha for hiddur mitzvah regarding Lechem Mishneh, or no? And if so, is the mitzvah of beautification an obligation for the bread itself (making it beautiful by braiding it) or for the plate/knife, or both?

Those all sound like hiddurim in seudat shabbat / kavod shabbat

Isn't a hiddur mitzvah by its very nature not a chiyuv, and that's why it's a hiddur mitzvah?

@יהושעק The Gemara says Hiddur Mitzvah is a chiyuv until 150% of the price of the basic way to do the mitzvah.

Hiddur Mitzvah is derived from Shemot 15:2 and Shabbat 133b on that verse.
Shemot 15:2
(ב) זֶ֤ה אֵלִי֙ וְאַנְוֵ֔הוּ
(2) This is my God and I will glorify Him;
שבת קל״ג ב:ה׳
דְּתַנְיָא:זֶה אֵלִי וְאַנְוֵהוּ, הִתְנָאֵה לְפָנָיו בְּמִצְוֹת: עֲשֵׂה לְפָנָיו סוּכָּה נָאָה, וְלוּלָב נָאֶה, וְשׁוֹפָר נָאֶה, צִיצִית נָאָה, סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה נָאֶה, וְכָתוּב בּוֹ לִשְׁמוֹ בִּדְיוֹ נָאֶה, בְּקוּלְמוֹס נָאֶה, בְּלַבְלָר אוּמָּן, וְכוֹרְכוֹ בְּשִׁירָאִין נָאִין.
Shabbat 133b
As it was taught in a baraita with regard to the verse: “This is my God and I will glorify Him”: Beautify yourself before Him in mitzvot. Make before Him a beautiful sukka, a beautiful lulav, a beautiful shofar, beautiful ritual fringes, a beautiful Sefer Torah scroll, and write in it His name in beautiful ink, with a beautiful quill by an expert scribe, and wrap the scroll in beautiful silk fabric.
The above is written in wide, general terms. So based on Shabbat 133b, the answer to the OP’s question is *“all of the above” (or "any of the above").
Hiddur mitzvah in relation to lechem mishnah can be achieved by beautification of amy or all of the challot, the bread knife, the challah cover, bread board and bread basket.
